# Magento How to Format Date in an Email Template

Tags: email, date, templates, magento, format

I need to format the date in an email template. The date gets included in the plain `.html` email as follows:

```
Dispatch Date: {{var order.getShippingDate()}}
```

Is there any way I can format this date? I've tried just using the standard PHP `date` function to format it to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strtotime any help? It can parse a data back to a unix timestamp, which is what date() expects as an input.

edit after comment:

You can try creating a custom version of app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php under the app/code/local folder (it goes here so magento updates don't overwrite it). It contains a method called getCreatedAtFormated  - you could apply the same principle to the shipping data and see if that achieves what you need to do.

Comment: Nope... it doesn't let me use any php functions inside of the curly braces.

Remember, this is in a .html file, so I guess the problem lies with the way that Magento parses the file.

Comment: Sweet... that was it! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can add block directive with custom template

{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/shipment/date.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}

and there format date by helper.

OR rewrite Filter which uses for parsing of templates and add your directive

```
 /**
    * Setup callbacks for filters
    *
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_modifiers['date'] = array($this, 'modifierDate');
    }

    public function modifierEscape($value, $format='d/m/Y')
    {
        return Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($value,$format);
    }
```

this is not tested code. just example.

Answer (score -2):

Dispatch Date: {{var order.getShippingDate()|formatDateTime:F j, Y}}