# Magento email template format date of invoice

Tags: php, email, templates, magento

I'm trying to apply the german format of a date to a Magento email. I can get the invoice date with

```
{{var invoice.created_at}}
```

but that gives me "2010-05-21 15:46:24". I would like to have 21.05.2010 and PHP doesn't work in the templates.

I'm totally new to Magento so please be patient :-P

Greetz
Spanky

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105474/magento-how-to-format-date-in-an-email-template

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105474/magento-how-to-format-date-in-an-email-template

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to override the method that sends the email to pass the date as a variable to the template (using the fifth argument of the sendTransactional() method).

Comment: which class would that have to be and where do I put my class so it get's called automatically?

Comment: This one, maybe : http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Order.html see this post for overriding : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041787/magento-email-templates
If it does not correspond to your email, grep for the last part of the path where it is located in the classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could also call the `order.getCreatedAtStoreDate()`-function:

```
Order date: {{var order.getCreatedAtStoreDate()}}
```

Comment: This does not reply to the question, another way could be using getCreatedAtFormated(format) where format can be short|medium|long|full. But still this does not completely resolve the problem.